# Removing a string in Python without removing repeating characters

Tags: python

I am printing a folder name to a text file containing data, and want to remove the external folders from the string. For example, **it is printing `C:\A3200\201808101040`, but I want to print `201808101040`**. When I use `str(os.getcwd().strip('C:\\A3200\\'))` to remove the external folders from being printed, the program returns `180810104`, which is weird because some of the zeros are removed but some aren't, etc. (it removed the beginning `20` and the ending `0`.)

I know that this could be done by getting the folder name a different way than `os.getcwd()`, but I am interested in this method of string manipulation for the future.

**How do I remove a certain string of characters within a full string without affecting the characters that are repeated later in the full string?**

Comment: `os.path.basename ("C:\A3200\201808101040")`?

Comment: That may work, but I would like to know for future reference how to just do it string-wise, in case I need to remove something else like "pear" from "pear tree", etc. where the "e" is in both words

Comment: my-string.replace('pear', '') will take "pear" out of pear tree

Comment: Can this question please be clarified? I feel like multiple questions are being posed in the comments of various answers. What are you trying to acheive? You can cross the 'pear tree' bridge when you need to remove the word 'pear' from the phrase 'pear tree'

Comment: I think there is one question being asked: How do I remove a certain string of characters within a full string without affecting the characters that are repeated later in the full string? There may be different ways of doing it for the file directory example, I want to do it in the exact same method as I would for the pear tree example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That may work, but I would like to know for future reference how to
>   just do it string-wise, in case I need to remove something else like
>   "pear" from "pear tree", etc. where the "e" is in both words

You could do `'pear tree'.replace('pear', '', 1).strip()`

Answer (score 1):

Strip takes a *set* of characters and removes from both sides until it encounters a character not in the set. This is why it eats your 2 and 0 but not the 1. You will probably have better luck with `os.getcwd().split(os.sep)[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
a=r"C:\A3200\201808101040" # make sure you read it raw
a[a.rindex("\\")+1:] #'201808101040'
```

**OR**

In case you just need 'C:\A3200' and '201808101040' seperated

```
a=r"C:\A3200\201808101040"
a.rsplit("\\",1)[1] #'201808101040'
a.rsplit("\\",1)[0] #'C:\A3200'
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this specific question is employing `os.path.basename()`.

In regards to your more broad question: "*How do I remove a certain string of characters within a full string without affecting the characters that are repeated later in the full string?*"

I would consider using a regular expression (regex). This allows you to specify positive and negative look-aheads / look-behinds, and many other useful tricks. In your case here, I would consider **searching** the string instead of actually **replacing** any characters in the string. Here is a regex example for your question:

```
import re

s = r'C:\A3200\201808101040'

matches = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', s)

print(matches)
```

Yields:

```
['3200', '201808101040']
```

Obviously, in this case, you are interested in the final match returned in `matches`, therefore you can access this via `matches[-1]`, which gives `201808101040`.

Comment: Is OP concerned about 3200? If so shouldn't it be A3200 after all it is a part of the path